# How to locally host a Django project?

Tags: python, django, localhost, web-hosting

I am trying to run a Django website, and I want the ability for all devices that are connected to the same router as my computer to be able to access the website. I have looked in several places, and questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51298664/how-to-host-a-django-website-in-my-pc-and-view-it-in-another-pc), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26311459/locally-hosting-django-project/26311702).

In summary, the first links says that I should run my server with `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`, and that will allow to access it from my cellphone. The second link said the same thing, but instead of `0.0.0.0`, it said that I should use my own IP address while running the `runserver` command. Neither approaches worked. I can access the website from my computer, but not from my cellphone, for example. (Both connected to 'X' network)

I really don't know what to do since I can't find another answer, possibly because I am not searching for the question correctly, but I would love it if anyone could help me.

I tried sharing internet from my cellphone and using its IP address, and that worked. I think this points out that it is maybe a problem with my router or internet provider. I don't know.

Comment: How are you launching this currently? Did you try with `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` which runs on all interfaces?  You'd then need to find the LAN IP address of your computer (possibly via router DHCP table) then use `<computers-IP>:8000` to connect to your app from the other devices...

Comment: Yeah, I am doing the 0.0.0.0 thing. And I found my LAN IP address (the IPv4) with `ipconfig`, and then tried to access the app through it with my cel and another computer. Nothing of this worked @v25

Comment: Sounds like a firewall issue.  Along the lines of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10506727/2052575). Might work if you specifically run the server on that IP instead of 0.0.0.0, but this mentions a dialogue which should appear.  Could be one of those where if you've dismissed it once, you need to go into firewall settings and specifically add a rule for that.

Comment: I already tried to run specifically at it with my IP instead of 0.0.0.0, but it doesn't work. 
How do I go to firewall settings? And what should I do? @v25

Comment: hi, what name your hosting ?

Comment: if you run the web on your computer you can do this python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:<Computer-IP> or localhost:<Computer-IP>, you can run the command ifconfig, find, eno and then you find inet 192.168.100.xx copy this

Answer (score 0):

if you run the web on your computer you can do this python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:Computer-IP or localhost:Computer-IP, you can run the command ifconfig, find, eno and then you find inet 192.168.100.xx copy this

don't forget to enter your application folder settings.py ALLOWED_HOSTS = [] change like this ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]

Comment: I am using a Windows computer, so I don't think this will work. Plus, as specified in my question, I have already tried those methods

Comment: Hi, there is no error, it just doesn't loads

Comment: ok i understand now, this error you have a url error which has a lot of data exceeding the maximum fetch, hi you can show your hosting traffic from terminal

Comment: ok. ```Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[03/Jan/2021 19:00:35] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6613
[03/Jan/2021 19:18:51] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6613``` I really don't think that is the issue since I only have these two requests

Comment: for the response I see it runs smoothly because 200, but the traffic is a lot when you respond to the url, try searching maybe you can find a problem there, I'll try to make it work

Comment: If you don't find anything wrong in traffic, it's probably just one error in the code